# Painting different vertical segments under curve using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, area

I am trying to create a simple line graph using d3 which segments the curve and paint each segment with a different colour. Currently I am only able to colour the whole area under the curve.

Current:
[image]

Attempting to achieve (Pardon me for the terrible colouring. In a rush for time):

[image]

This is bits of relevant code. Please help!

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear();  
var y = d3.scaleLinear();

//Set the range of the data
x.domain([0, Math.max(endGrowth, endPlateau) ,maxX]).range([0, width*0.8, width]);
y.domain([0, maxY]).range([height, 0]);

//Define the area under the Graph
var area1 = d3.area()
.x0(function(d){ 
    return x(d.Rank);
})
.y1(function(d){ return y(d.Elements);})
.y0(height);


//Add the colored regions
svg.append("path")
.data([data])
.attr("class", "areaUnderGraph")
.attr("fill", "blue")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + leftMarginLabel + ",0)") 
.attr("d", area1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the area under the curve is one path, so it can only be colored one color. The simplest way to color different portions under the curve different colors is to split them up in data. It's not clear where data is coming from, but you'd take sub-sections of the array, like

```
var segments = [data.slice(0, 2), data.slice(2)];

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(segments)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d) { /* use d to choose a color */ })
```

That's the gist: you'd have multiple slices of the data, and instead of one path, you'd create multiple paths that you can color as you wish.